# Angular JS - orderBy one key while keeping at the end results when another key is 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects like this:

```
$scope.cars = [
  {"brand":"McLaren","price":70,"stock":0},
  {"brand":"Renault","price":10,"stock":0},
  {"brand":"Ferrari","price":100,"stock":3},
  {"brand":"Lamborghini","price":50,"stock":2},
  {"brand":"Porsche","price":30,"stock":1},
  {"brand":"Seat","price":120,"stock":0},
  {"brand":"Audi","price":10,"stock":3},
];
```

I would like to order them in my view in Angular from high to low price, but keeping the ones that have `"stock":0` at the end. Is there any straightforward way to do that in angular? Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lN4pBLtKjirds5e52LHV?p=preview) with my example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foregoing the comparator function, we can sort by "stock == 0" because the order by strings are angular expressions. this Is much simpler than my initial comparator solution.

```
`orderBy:['stock==0','-price']`
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HUHaHLwCR4rkLvHm6K0u?p=preview

```css
li p {
  font-family:Arial;
  color:black;
}
.noStock p {
  font-family:Arial;
  color:gray;
  font-style:italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
    <p>{{title}}</p>
    
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="car in cars | orderBy:['stock==0','-price']" ng-class="{'noStock':car.stock==0}">
        <p>{{ car.brand }} ({{ car.price }}) <span ng-if="car.stock==0">Out of Stock</span></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  
    $scope.title ="Cars";
    
  $scope.cars = [
    {"brand":"McLaren","price":70,"stock":0},
      {"brand":"Renault","price":10,"stock":0},
    {"brand":"Ferrari","price":100,"stock":3},
      {"brand":"Lamborghini","price":50,"stock":2},
      {"brand":"Porsche","price":30,"stock":1},
      {"brand":"Seat","price":120,"stock":0},
      {"brand":"Audi","price":10,"stock":3},
    ];
  
 });
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

orderBy takes a comparator function, which gets pairs of two objects 
`{value: '<your element>', type: <string, number, ...>, index: <element position>}`and is supposed to return `<-1,0,1>`.

you could implement a custom comparator that compares elements stock , considering only 0 and >=1, and sorts by price and finally index.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.title = "Cars";

  $scope.cars = [  {"brand":"McLaren","price":70,"stock":0},
  {"brand":"Renault","price":10,"stock":0},
  {"brand":"Ferrari","price":100,"stock":3},
  {"brand":"Lamborghini","price":50,"stock":2},
  {"brand":"Porsche","price":30,"stock":1},
  {"brand":"Seat","price":120,"stock":0},
  {"brand":"Audi","price":10,"stock":3},
  ];

  $scope.carComparator = function(v1, v2) {
    var car1 = v1.value
    var car2 = v2.value

    // cars without stock are always "less" than cars with stock
    var stock1 = car1 && car1.stock > 0
    var stock2 = car2 && car2.stock > 0

    if (stock1 != stock2) {
      return stock2 - stock1;
    }
    
    //if stock didnt decide, we sort by price.
    //if 2 is more expensive we return a number >0 so it gets sortet above 1, if 2 is less expensive the result is <0 to put it below 1
    var price1 = car1 && car1.price
    var price2 = car2 && car2.price

    if (price1 != price2) {
      return price2 - price1;
    }

    return index2 - index1; //fallback if equal by stock and by price so sorting always finishes
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
    <p>{{title}}</p>

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="car in cars | orderBy:'+':false:carComparator " ng-class="{'noStock':car.stock==0}">
        <p>{{ car.brand }} ({{ car.price }})</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

the way this works is that stock1 and 2 are converted into boleans and used as numbers. so any stock >=1 counts as 1, any stock <= 0 counts as 0. then , if either car is in stock and the other isnt, it returns 1 or -1 to push the first or second car "higher".

for price, its which ever is larger. so if price 1 is larger we return a value <0 , if price 2 is larger we return >0

As a fallback we sort by the original array index, because we need some definitive order, otherwise sorting would never finish (angular guards against this, but we shouldnt rely on it)

Comment: @Joe82 ive added an implementation, the actual sort order is determined by the return a-b lines. if you swap them, it reverses that criterion

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Wouldn't it be possible to implement your comparator as first criteria in an array in the orderBy, and then price as second? Something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/lN4pBLtKjirds5e52LHV?p=preview

Comment: I think so, I didnt try it, but also had the idea to forego the comparator entirely because sort strings are expressions. -price literally sorts by negative price, so you should be able to sort by "stock not 0, -price"

Comment: Yep, you're right, `ng-repeat="car in cars | orderBy:['stock == 0','-price']"` did the trick. Thanks! http://plnkr.co/edit/lN4pBLtKjirds5e52LHV?p=preview

Comment: @Joe82 good call. i should have tried making it work with expressions: `orderBy:['stock==0','-price']` ... http://plnkr.co/edit/HUHaHLwCR4rkLvHm6K0u?p=preview . i guess custom comparators are only needed when the conditions get way more complicated

Comment: Could you add that to your answer, so I could mark it as correct? I think it will save more than one headache :)

Comment: wow... 18 seconds apart... i should type faster. to be honest ill make it a seperate answer. its a different approach, and reading about custom comparators isnt what "solved" your question. give me a minute

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-repeat="car in cars | orderBy:'-price' | orderBy:'-stock'"
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Can you explain your answer?